# Nested transaction on google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

If I want all deletes execute all-or-nothing.

1. If nothing changed. Will the group of deletes be atomic?
2. If I remove outer transaction, will something change?
3. If I remove only inner transaction, will group be atomic?
4. Ig I replace for-cycle with a batch delete and leave only outer transaction?

```
    // inside event plan dao
    public void delete(EventPlan eventPlan) {
      final Objectify ofy = Objectify.beginTransaction();
      try {
        final ActivityDAO activityDao = new ActivityDAO();
        for (final Activity activity : eventPlan.getActivities()) {
          activityDao.delete(activity);
        }
        ofy.getTxn().commit();
      } finally {
        if (ofy.getTxn().isActive()) {
          ofy.getTxn().rollback();
        |
      }
    }
```

```
   

    // inside activity dao
    public void delete(Activity activity) {
          final Objectify ofy = Objectify.beginTransaction();
       try {
          // do some logic in here, delete activity and commit txn
       } finally {
          // check and rollback as normal
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Objectify 3.1 then all transactions are [XG-transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions), which can operate on max 5 different entity groups, i.e. if your Activities do not have common parent (= putting them in the same entity group) then you can only delete max five in one transaction.

1. No, you are using parallel transactions ( one outer, multiple inner).
2. No, outer transaction has no operation executed, so it does nothing. There are multiple inner transaction (loop) each doing it's own delete.
3. Yes, you must perform all operations within one transaction for operations to be atomic. If you remove inner transactions you are on the right path. However, Entity Group transaction limit still applies: all entities touched within a transaction must belong to the same Entity Group, or (since XG is enabled by default) to max five different Entity Groups (see above). Note if you don't explicitly put entity in Entity Group (by setting parent) then every entity gets it's own Entity Group.
4. Yes, batch delete is better then delete in loop (due to efficiency) but all transaction rules in point 3. still apply.

Comment: I guess these rules roughly apply if I am using pure datastore transactions - imagine Im not using objectify. So the nested transactions in fact rewrite some marker on the entity group and override and cancel any outer transactions? So having inner transaction (all happening in a loop) side by side another put operation, that put operation (contained in a loop) will not be part of any transaction at all? (b/c outer transaction got ignored?) Or does the outer transaction still apply?

Comment: Every time you call `beginTransaction()` (in objectify or elsewhere, they are all wrapper of low-level API) you you get a new transaction.

Comment: So any inner transaction starts a new transaction on the entity group and makes all outer transactions no-ops. So it makes no sense to nest transactions in GAE, unless your fine with that the outer transaction becomes just a waste of code (for a particular scenario of execution). Right?:-

Comment: On GAE there is no "starting transactions on the entity groups", there is no locking, etc.. GAE Transaction model relies on internal version number on EG - when transaction commits it checks if version changed and throws exception.

Comment: From the docs: App Engine uses optimistic concurrency control by checking the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. Upon commiting a transaction for the entity groups, App Engine again checks the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. If it has changed since our initial check, App Engine throws an exception. For an explanation of entity groups, see the Datastore Overview page. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction

Comment: if the entity changes - I think they mean outside of transaction - then on commit it throws exception. Either I was meaning something different or I don't get it. For sure I created another question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11829892/271996

Comment: It does not matter where change happens: in another transaction or outside transaction - the original transaction will not succeed.