# Nested transactions on google app engine datastore 3

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

Question is: does ds.put(employee) happen in transaction? Or does the outer transaction get erased/overriden by the transaction in saveRecord(..)?

1. Once error is thrown at line datastore.put(..) at some point in the for-loop (let's say i==5), will previous puts originating on the same line get rollbacked?
2. What about puts happening in the saveRecord(..). I suppose those will not get rollbacked.

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (int i=0; 1<10; i++) {
            Key employeeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", "Joe");
            Entity employee = datastore.get(employeeKey);
            employee.setProperty("vacationDays", 10);

            datastore.put(employee);

            Entity employeeRecord = createRecord("record", employeeKey);
            saveRecord(employeeRecord);
        }
    txn.commit();
    } finally {
        if (txn.isActive()) {
            txn.rollback();
        }
    }

    public void saveRecord(Entity entity) {
       datastore.beginTransaction();
       try {
          // do some logic in here, delete activity and commit txn
          datastore.put(entity);
       } finally {
        if (datastore.getCurrentTransaction().isActive()) {
          datastore.getCurrentTransaction().rollback();
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ds.beginTransaction()` your custom code? Does it return the same transaction or new transaction on every call?

Comment: ds is just a reference to the API DataStore object.

Comment: I eddited the original example that was too wague... Pleas answer for the last time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll assume you are using low-level Datastore API. Note that `getTransaction()` does not exist. I'll assume you meant `datastoreService.getCurrentTransaction()`.

[`DatastoreService.beginTransaction()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#beginTransaction%28%29) will return a Transaction, that is considered a current transaction on the same thread until you call `beginTransaction()` again.  Since you call `beginTransaction()` in a loop inside "outer" transaction, it breaks your "outer" code: after the loop is finished `ds.getCurrentTransaction()` does not return the same transaction. Also, `put()` implicitly uses current transaction.

So first you must fix outer code to save transaction as [shown in example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Using_Transactions):

```
public void put(EventPlan eventPlan) {
  Transaction txn = ds.beginTransaction();
  try {
    for (final Activity activity : eventPlan.getActivities()) {
      save(activity, getPlanKey(eventPlan)); // PUT

      // IMPORTANT - also pass transaction and use it
      // (I assume this is some internal helper method)
      ds.put(txn, activity, getSubPlanKey(eventPlan)); //subplan's parent is eventPlan
    }
    txn.commit();
  } finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) 
      txn.rollback();
  }
}
```

Now on to questions:

1. Yes, because all puts are now part of the same transaction (after you fix the code) and you call `txn.rollback()` on it in case of errors.
2. No, of course not. They are part of different transactions.

Comment: I eddited the original example that was too wague... Pleas answer for the last time...